# Custom Plugin for ZenDesk Tickets

Tags: plugin-development, craft3, plugin-craftcommerce, plugin-craftcommerce2

I need all of the custom fields on an order submitted to ZenDesk to create a new ticket once the order is completed.

Once a ticket is created in ZenDesk, we will need the ticket number saved on a new custom field on the order. This will be used later for grabbing comments on the ticket.

Comment: This is a statement, not a question.  Are you asking if there is a plugin already (pretty sure there is not one that does exactly this) - or are you asking if it is possible/how to write it (it is possible, and it's not super hard to write - I have for instance done exactly this internally with Freshdesk).  It would be helpful if you could clarify what you are actually asking...

Comment: @Raj, it would be helpful if you could clarify what you're asking here. We remove posts that _aren't_ questions or answers this site's meant for, and you're likely to get more help if there's a clear question!

Answer (score 2):

There is a Zendesk plugin for Craft CMS that could be of use:

https://plugins.craftcms.com/zendesk

> This plugin can work either as a dashboard widget on your clients website, or you can post to it from a frontend form on your own website.